# Access violation exception when deleting an array

Tags: c++, memory-management, c++-cli, access-violation

I'm getting "Access violation reading location" exception when deleting the allocated memory as follow.

I have a native dll compiled against Visual Studio 2010(toolset: v100) C++ compiler.I have a managed dll wrapper for it which is compiled against toolset v90 as I want to target .net 2.0.

The managed wrapper passes the reference to pointer (double *&myArray) to one of the native dll function call, which internally creates a dynamic array and initializes the data.

However, when managed wrapper tries to release the wrapper by calling delete [] myArray, it throws the exception. It seems working fine If I ask native dll to free it.

Is it because of protected native dll address space that I'm getting the exception ? If I compile native dll with v90 toolset, the wrapper seems to delete the array without any exception which is weird.

What is the best way to delete the memory in such a use case ?

```
//Managed.cpp
void InitializeData()
{
    double *myArray;
    myNativeObj->InitializeArray(myArray);
    delete[] myArray; // <-- Exception here
}

//UnManaged.cpp
void InitializeArray(double *& myArray)
{
    myArray = new double[get_length()];
    //Initialize data to my array.
}
```

Thanks,
Mudassir

Comment: What is the data type of `myNativeObj`? Are you sure that the intended function is being called.

Comment: Did you initialized `myNativeObj` before call `myNativeObj->InitializeArray(myArray);`

Comment: Need an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), the code looks fine as-is.

Comment: can you post what exception are throw, with all runtime error messages?

Answer (score 4):

You're allocating in one C++ runtime (v100) and freeing in another (v90); that's just asking for trouble.

You should call `delete[]` in the same DLL from which you called `new[]` (or, at least from another DLL which uses the same runtime library).  Is this complicated and messy?  Yes; that's why COM (and then .NET) was invented.

Comment: +1 Nailed it, apparently I was paying too much attention to the code and not enough to the surrounding text to notice this rather important detail >_>. That said, that's why they invented _COM_ – .NET just got to reap the benefits of prior experience.