# Why can't a pointer be deleted across assemblies?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++-cli

Recently, I have found ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15286300/access-violation-exception-when-deleting-an-array)) that a pointer (or at least an array) cannot be deleted in a different assembly from which its memory is created. From what I know, a pointer is a variable in the memory that has as value the address of another variable in the memory. As such, why can't the value of a pointer (the address of the variable) be erased, and its memory freed from another assembly?

Comment: What are you calling an assembly?  Is this perhaps the same as a translation unit?

Comment: You use 'assembly' here but I think you potentially mean library or DLL.  Anyway, the underlying implementation of `new` and `delete` could vary between the runtimes used by those DLLs/libraries, which would cause corruption when mixing and matching.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, I came to C++ from .Net, and use assembly and library as synonyms (actually I don't know very well the difference). @Joe, don't different implementations of `new` and `delete` do the same? Can you give an example where there would be a problem?

Comment: Read this: [Allocating and freeing memory across module boundaries](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/09/15/755966.aspx).

Comment: Good link you got there @DCoder, I just read and marked it for future reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any dynamic allocation needs to go back on the same heap that it was allocated from. Each  DLL (and I expect an `assembly` is corresponding to a DLL) is capable of having its own heap, so you need to free it in the same DLL that it was allocated from, or strange things (undefined behaviour - for example errors or crashes) will happen.

So, unless you KNOW that two different modules (DLLs, asemblies) have the same heap, then you can't free something in one module that was allocated in another.

The requirement to return something to the heap it came from is a bit like returning a library book to the "wrong" library - it would cause all manner of confusion when the librarian can't find the book in the library it came from, and the "new" library wouldn't have any knowledge of the book either. Imagine if we all did this when we go to our libraries... The heap will contain internal data structures that "track" the objects in the heap. If we suddenly start putting them back where they don't belong, strange things will happen.

Comment: Note that "each DLL has its own heap" need not  be true.  You can compile DLLs to use a shared heap.  You can also compile them to use individual heaps.

Comment: Thanks, amended to clarify.

Comment: @MatsPetersson, thanks for the answer. I think the library analogy also makes it clearer and more interesting.

Comment: @vonbrand, isn't C or C++ used in another platforms, with its inherent problems? (and I'm not being sarcastic, I really don't know)

Comment: @JoãoMiguel: It is possible to have this problem in other OS's, yes. Any OS where memory allocation isn't done from a single heap will have this problem (unless the OS has some sort of special mechanism to track "where was this allocated"). And of course, both C and C++ allows a programmer to produce a home-made version of memory allocation - and of course, if some memory is allocated from, say, `mmap` in Linux, you can't just pass it to `free` or `delete` to de-allocate it.

Comment: @JoãoMiguel, in Linux the allocations go _all_ through the same underlying mechanisms, to the same heap. Even if parts where compiled with different versions of the compiler. I really thought this was very odd when I saw the question...

Comment: @vonbrand, that's amazing! One more reason for me to fully switch to Linux (I currently run it under the VM).